# How To 'Flush' A Jest Mock (without using await)

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I come from the AngularJS world but now using React and Jest (with Jest Mock).

I'd like to do this....

```
test('should update internal tracking variable', async () => {
        api.post = jest.fn().mock;

        expect(obj.postCallFinished).toBe(false)
        obj.begin() //this calls api.post internally with await
        expect(obj.postCallFinished).toBe(false)

        api.post.flush()
        expect(obj.postCallFinished).toBe(true)   

})
```

I don't want to use await in this instance on the `obj.begin` call. I need more fine grain control and want to check internal tracking variables so that I can slowly step through all the callbacks of my app (without breaking encapsulation on the functions). I need to do state based testing and it's important that I can slowly step through each blocking call in turn.

Please can someone help me figure out how I get control over the promise and slowly resolve the mock imperatively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `begin` is an `async` function that calls `await` on a series of `async` functions.

You can spy on the functions called within `begin` and retrieve the `Promise` that each returns by using [`mockfn.mock.results`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresults).  Then you can `await` each of those `Promises` individually within the test to check the state at each step.

Here is a simple example to get you started:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.state = 0;
  }

  async first() {
    await Promise.resolve();  // <= do something asynchronous
    this.state = 1;
  }

  async second() {
    await Promise.resolve();  // <= do something asynchronous
    this.state = 2;
  }

  async begin() {
    await this.first();
    await this.second();
    await Promise.resolve();  // <= do something asynchronous
    this.state = 3;
  }
}

test('walk through begin', async () => {
  const firstSpy = jest.spyOn(MyClass.prototype, 'first');
  const secondSpy = jest.spyOn(MyClass.prototype, 'second');

  const instance = new MyClass();
  const promise = instance.begin();
  expect(instance.state).toBe(0);  // Success!
  await firstSpy.mock.results[0].value;  // <= wait for the Promise returned by first
  expect(instance.state).toBe(1);  // Success!
  await secondSpy.mock.results[0].value;  // <= wait for the Promise returned by second
  expect(instance.state).toBe(2);  // Success!
  await promise;  // <= wait for the Promise returned by begin
  expect(instance.state).toBe(3);  // Success!
})
```